# Heat of hydrogenation

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

If benzene is more stable than cyclohexane then why is the heat of hydrogenation of benzene negative, ie heat is released during the formation of cyclohexane from benzene ?

Comment: What do you mean by "benzene is more stable than cyclohexane". Can you provide a source for that statement?

Comment: Related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/108726/48509

Comment: If it is exothermic means cyclohexane must be more stable than benzene right? But it is not so. How is that possible?

Comment: "But it is not so". By what measure is it not so? What makes you say, "benzene is more stable than cyclohexane".

Comment: Because benzene is aromatic? That's what others told me but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

All hydrogenation reactions, not just for benzene, are exothermic. You can refer  [Why are hydrogenation reactions exothermic](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44371/why-are-hydrogenation-reactions-exothermic) .